# on exam day or on the exam day?

Tags: articles

Google tells me it is the former, and it does feel more nature to say "on exam day", but if I do some grammar analysis, it seems quite puzzling. "day" is of course countable, therefore should either take on a plural form or a definitive article "the", according to [image: this]

P.S. I am trying to write something like, "on exam day, you should bring your ID card and a bottle of water."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence that's proposed in the question.

---

In this case, it's not really *day* that's the noun, but the two-word noun *exam day*. It's like how *hot dog* and *ice cream*, although each composed of two words, are actually single entities.

Further, *exam day* is treated differently than *day*, or most nouns.

---

Saying *on exam day* is treated the same way as saying *on Wednesday*.

While *Wednesday* is indeed a countable noun, we don't normally put an article in front of it. However, we do in some cases, and, in others, it's not actually wrong to do so—just a bit unusual.

The following are common constructions.

Questions:

> "When are you taking the trash out?"
> "When are you going back to campus?"

Answers:

> "On Wednesday."
> "On exam day."
>
> "On *the* first Wednesday *of the month.*
> "On *the* first exam day *of the week.*

But it *is* possible to use an article when you normally wouldn't, if a particular context makes it sound okay.

Questions:

> "There are two days on which you can take out the trash: Tuesday and Wednesday. On which of those days will you do it?"
>
> "There are two times when you can go to campus: exam day and free-period day. On which of those days will you do it?"

Answers:

> "On *the* Wednesday."
> "On *the* exam day."

Although we would normally leave out the article, those answers still make sense with it. The article specifies a specific day—in this case, one as opposed to the other.

It's similar to the following.

Question:

> "I've got two jelly beans: red and blue. Which one would you like?"

Answers:

> "Red."
> "*The* red.
> "*The* red one.

All three answers work.

---

As with most things involving English, there are exceptions to general rules.

This is not so much a matter of grammar per se, but a matter of common usage and what's idiomatic.

Why we've come to use these conventions with certain words, and in certain contexts, I couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked this up on Google, and below is the search result:
When moving the describing noun to before the main noun (moving exam to before day), exam is a noun used as an adjective to describe the day (an "attributive noun"). Such nouns are not inflected for case or gender because adjectives are not inflected. Thus it should be left alone and "on the exam day" is right.
Hope it helped!